# Code blocks isn't displaying the program arguments properly

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

My code is as follows in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        printf("Hello world! The arguments are %d, argc is %d and the string is %s\n",argc,i,argv);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm unable to see arguments properly in the output. It sort of comes encrypted.

I went to projects-> set program arguments. It's not working though. Please help?

Comment: `argv` is not `char[]` it is a pointer to `char[]`.

Comment: Why do you expect that your program displays all the arguments ? It display _argc_ times the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are printing a pointer to pointer, as your compiler is telling you:

```
test.c:12:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 4 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("Hello world! The arguments are %d, argc is %d and the string is %s\n",argc,i,argv);
         ^
```

`argv` is an array of pointers and you want to print the string pointed by each item of that array:

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        printf("Hello world! The arguments are %d, argc is %d and the string is %s\n",argc,i,argv[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```